# IdentityServer4: Unable to load certificate, having trouble loading the certificate

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, identityserver4, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm unable to load the x509 certificate.

Issue: It can't find the certificate. I checked and it's right there! :(

---

```
    public static X509Certificate2 Get()
    {
        var assembly = typeof(Certificate).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
        var names = assembly.GetManifestResourceNames();

        /***********************************************************************************************
         *  Please note that here we are using a local certificate only for testing purposes. In a 
         *  real environment the certificate should be created and stored in a secure way.
         **********************************************************************************************/
        using (var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("Identity.API.Certificate.idsrv3test.pfx"))
        {
            return new X509Certificate2(ReadStream(stream), "idsrv3test");
        }
    }

    private static byte[] ReadStream(Stream input)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            int read;
            while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

**Reference** https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers/blob/38ade408629a606bc63bb09ea1f4e54ca473e617/src/Services/Identity/Identity.API/Certificate/Certificate.cs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am loading the certificate from Startup.cs with the following line of code

```
X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(Path.Combine(_env.ContentRootPath, "cetname.pfx"), "password");
```

Comment: does it work? and where did you place the certificate? in root?

Comment: yes, in the root folder, I am using certificate like this

Answer (score 1):

You will need to change the Build Action on the .pfx file to an EmbeddedResource. Easy to do in Visual Studio in the properties window on the file.

You can see the result in the csproj like this:
https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers/blob/38ade408629a606bc63bb09ea1f4e54ca473e617/src/Services/Identity/Identity.API/Identity.API.csproj

Comment: I tried this, it didnt work! so i just read directly from the file, that worked but now I have a different issue.